# sql aggregating the selection results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to aggregate all of my selection results:

I have a `select user result1 from....)` returning 2 columns:

```
user   results1
****   ********
user1  5
user2  8
```

I also have another query `select user result2 from....)` returning another 2 columns:

```
user   results2
****   ********
user1  9
user2  5
user3  15
```

How would I join the results together with 3 columns to make something like:

```
user   results1   results2
****   ********   ********
user1  5          9
user2  8          5
user3            15
```

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't sure that the `User` value exists in both tables, then you should use a `FULL JOIN` to query the tables.  A [`FULL JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join) or `FULL OUTER JOIN` (`OUTER` is optional) will return the rows from both tables, but if the `user` doesn't exist in one of them, you will still get results:

```
select 
  [user] = coalesce(r1.[user], r2.[user]),
  r1.results1,
  r2.results2
from result1 r1
full join result2 r2
  on r1.[user] = r2.[user];
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de639/1).

The problem with using an `INNER JOIN` is it will require that the `User` is in both tables. If you try to use a `RIGHT JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` - then you may still not return all users and their results.

If you have multiple queries that you are trying to combine, then you can use a CTE or subqueries:

```
;with query1 as
(
  select [user], result1 from results1
),
query2 as
(
  select [user], result2 from results2
)
select 
  [user] = coalesce(q1.[user], q2.[user]),
  q1.result1,
  q2.result2
from query1 q1
full join query2 q2
  on q1.[user] = q2.[user]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query: (As you want to combine the result of two separate answers from queries)

```
SELECT b.User, a.Result1, b.Result2 
from (select user, result1 from....) a
     full outer join (select user, result2 from....) b 
where a.user = b.user
```

Comment: Hi Verra actually Table1 and Table2 are resultset with 2 columns, how would I achieve same thing as our code above ?

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` assumes that `table1` doesn't have unique users, if it does then you will lose rows.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
select b.User, a.Result1, b.Result2 
from table1 A
full outer join table2 b 
where a.user = b.user
```

a Full outer Join will give you all records only in table a and b + common records.

Comment: This is correct but i think you should resolve table1 and table2 using WITH clause, i think this is what OP wants

Comment: Can you please elaborate @Aramillo?

Comment: check bluefeet's answer